# How to prevent slider labels overlapping in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, slider

[image: my slider]

I have this slider in MUI where I indicate with an emoji the current % which is fetched from an API, but at the moment it's very close to 75% and on mobile the two labels overlap. Is there a way to move only the emoji label above the slider, preventing the overlapping?

Other viable solutions to overlapping (without removing labels) are fine.

Comment: zindex is right answer to solve the overlapping issue as answered by @G.Roussel  share your code in codesandbox. without code its difficult to answer your questions.

Comment: @PrashantJangam no because the two labels would still overlap

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the z-index property on the emoji.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/z-index.

Like so:

```
.emoji {
  z-index: 2
}
```

Comment: no the labels would still overlap